What is the level of the various technologies in Shadow of the Apt?
I have only read as far as part way through Dragonfly Falling, and during the various battles there are 'automotives' but at the same time the rest of the general technology level seems to be much less 'advanced'.
It seems various peoples are anywhere from bronze age to early renaissance, but with automotives and electric trains it's hard to know what level each specific technology the author is trying to imply by saying 'automotives' or 'fixed wing fliers'.
